# Footer size growing when page extends,... yet it has no reason to

Tags: css, wordpress

Have a look at the homepage: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/ now if you make the browser fill the screen like I do (1680x1050) the footer seems to gain an extra hundred or so pxls? Here is my proof:

Normal View:

[image]

When I make my browser size bigger:

[image]

Its really odd - I need to work this one out.
When you have a look on an IPad its even worse.

Ideas?

Comment: It's definitely something with all the positioning and margin adjustments of your other divs and not a browser bug. I just set the "hold" div and all of the other divs inside of "wrapper" except for the footer to display:none. Then I filled up the wrapper with arbitrary <p>...</p> tags to make the page scroll again, and the issue went away. (You can try this yourself dynamically with Chrome's developer tools and editing the HTML.) To figure out exactly where it is will require more investigation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer isn't actually becoming larger. If you check out firebug and inspect the element, it is still 100px. Your browser is actually allowing you to scroll past the end of your page, and since your footer's position is relative to your page, it stops when your content does.

You may want to try out a "Sticky Footer" solution... one can be found here: http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/

Answer (score 0):

This extra space is not footer (that size doesn't change), but whole html/body, but unfortunately I don't have more precise idea. Error still occurs after disabling JS, so it's not the cause.
The weirdest thing is that it seems to be connected with state of window (is it maximalised or not).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the height of that #wrapper ends up being around 1354 px. Whenever your screen extends past that height, you get the extra space. Using chrome dev tools, change the background color to something highly visible (I chose red) and then set the #wrapper height to 1500 px or more while you have your screen size maximized. You can see that you are no longer able to scroll down past the bottom of the div as the height of the div is > the available screen resolution height.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at `<span id="followme">`.  In the CSS (style.css), #followme is set to have a height of 100%.  If you zoom way out in Chrome, inspect the #followme element, and change your browser size you'll notice that the followme element is actually covering up a lot of the page.

It may not be the only factor you need to look at, but seems to be the most likely culprit when examining it.